# crontab + SSH client, disk space leaking problem, how to solve it?

Tags: ssh, cron

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I'm doing something weird on my system.

In `crontab -e`, I have a line like this:

```
@reboot sleep 11 && sshpass -p '123456' ssh -D *:7070 socksclient@localhost
```

so that an ssh client program runs automatically on system startup, acting as a SOCK5 server at port 7070.

But something bad happens. My root partition is slowly running out of space, and I can see this leakage with `df`, about 100 bytes per second.

After some investigation, `lsof | grep deleted` reveals that it is `ssh` or `sshpass` grabbing [ a file handle to a deleted file-system path(**/tmp/#16** in the attached image)] and append content to it continuously, so it is sneakingly hogging my disk space.

[image: Snap0651 lsof grep delete chh tip.png]

BTW: If I run `sshpass -p '123456' ssh -D *:7070 socksclient@localhost` manually from Linux console, those `(delete)` entries will not appear.

Those leaked disk space can not be revealed with `du`, and, they can be freed only by killing the ssh or sshpass process.

**So my question is:** I want my ssh client to run with system startup, but eliminate disk space leakage. How to achieve that?

I'll be appreciative if someone can tell:

- What's the current size of a `deleted` file?
- how can I know what content(text) is being appended to the /tmp/#16 file? Maybe some program similar to the [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) on Windows?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `-N` to your ssh command? otherwise it may be trying to start a login shell for `socksclient` with every invocation... I wonder if that's what is leaving dangling file handles?

Comment: please change this method: your password is leaking too ;-)

Comment: @steeldriver I don't think It is leaking handles, bcz the `(deleted)` entry count is constant. It is just appending bytes to one/some existing opened handles.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you for pointing out this. I have made a workaround: In `/etc/passwd`, I change socks5client's shell to be a dumb Bash script(just display a welcome message and sleep), so the socks5client login would not cause much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this help.

Get the PID and FD of process holding that 'deleted' file/fd and use stat/cat/peekfd etc.
It has to be still running cause file even in deleted state is here (under active process).

> $ ps uax | grep "your process name"  **#to get the PID**
>
> $ lsof -p "PID id You found" **#to see open files and their FD**
>
> $ stat /proc/${mypid}/fd/${myfd}
>
> $ cat /proc/${mypid}/fd/${myfd}
>
> $ peekfd /proc/${mypid}/fd/${myfd}

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I have figured it out from peekfd (`sudo peekfd 1757 7` to peek into PID 1757, fd=7). My custom login script writes log messages continuously to stdout, but the stdout is really NOT a terminal, but a file handle to `/tmp/#16` . I'm not sure who created that `/tmp/#16` file, probably `cron`, so the bloating of `/tmp/#16`. Now, in my bash script, I check the stdout with `[ -t 0 ]`, and if it is not a real terminal, i will not write out log message. Problem solved.